# airwatch-sdk-plugin not recognised in ionic 3 app

Tags: ionic3, airwatch

I've created a brand new blank ionic 3 app and run the command "npm i airwatch-sdk-plugin" and then "ionic cordova platform add android".

In app.components I have this code ...

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      window.plugins.airwatch.setSDKEventListener( function( event, error ) {
        if( event === "initSuccess" ) {
          alert( 'airwatch initialised' );
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        alert( 'airwatch error: ' + JSON.stringify( error ) );
      });
      
    });
  }
}
```

The editor Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 is reporting the plugins does not exist on type window. I can change this line to ...

```html
(<any>window).plugins
```

to remove the editor error, but when I run the project with "ionic serve" the browser will report this error ...

TypeError: Cannot read property 'airwatch' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the installation guide, below command should be added before any other plugin is added to the app:

```
ionic cordova plugin add airwatch-sdk-plugin
```

As per the installation guide, the functions are available in the window.plugins.airwatch object. Hence you need to declare `window` variable as shown below:

```
declare var window: any;
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I've removed all plugins, so the plugins directory is empty. I uninstalled the airwatch-sdk-plugin. I also uninstalled the Adnroid platform. I then re-installed the airwatch-sdk-plugin and put declare var window: any; above @Component and inside the platform.ready I put the code window.plugins.airwatch.setSDKEventListener(event,info) code. I get this error ... Cannot read property 'airwatch' of undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Just want to know, whether you are using ionic cordova run android and real devices too for testing?

Comment: I'm using ionic cordova build android and running on device. I also have the intentShim installed and to call that I do .... window.plugins.intentShim and via Chrome:inspect I can put a breakpoint there and I can see that within window.plugins is just the intentShim listed and not the airwatch plugin. Obviously, this would suggect the plugin isn't installed properly. What would the steps be if I was to start from a brand new project ... ionic start airwatch blank ?

Comment: My ionic.info reports this ... Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.5 (C:\Users\Graham.Simmons\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v6.10.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 4.6.1
   OS                : Windows 10

Comment: May I know how you have installed the plugin? i.e. using "cordova plugin add airwatch-sdk-plugin" or "npm i airwatch-sdk-plugin". Also can you please try this command "ionic cordova plugin ls"

Comment: I used this ... npm i airwatch-sdk-plugin and running the other command I get ... $ ionic cordova plugin ls
> cordova plugin ls
No plugins added. Use `cordova plugin add <plugin>`.

Comment: and this too (was too big to paste in with last results) .... net.js:654
    throw new TypeError(
    ^

TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
    at Socket.write (net.js:654:11)
    at process.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Graham.Simmons\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin\ionic:9:63)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at process.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at emitPendingUnhandledRejections (internal/process/promises.js:66:22)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:110:7)

Comment: I've just uninstalled the npm version and installed the cordova plugin add airwatch-sdk-plugin version and now ionic cordova plugin ls shows > cordova plugin ls
com.airwatch.awsdkplugin 1.2.0 "airwatch-sdk-plugin"

Comment: Please try running the app now

Comment: ionic cordova build android fails with this error ... Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'. and also Could not find :AirWatchSDK-release-17.6.3.2-SNAPSHOT:.

Comment: Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Do I need to install some SDK to the Android Studio so the build knows what airwatch is? If so, what do I need to do? Please help as I'm going around in circles here.